# Error al insertar registros con PDO en php

Tags: php, sql, poo, pdo

Bueno tengo el siguiente error, que cuando intento registrar datos en la base de datos me aparece el siguiente error

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''CÓDIGOARTÍCULO', 'SECCIÓN', 'NOMBREARTÍCULO', 'PRECIO', 'FECHA', 'IMPORTADO' at line 1 En la Linea 36

Sale que el error radica en la Linea 36 por algun problema de error de sintax en la instruccion SQL pero llevo rato intentando encontrarla y no puedo encontrar nada, ademas que si fuese por los campos de la BD tampoco porque los campos son:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El codigo es el siguiente:

```
    $c_articulo=$_POST["c_articulo"];
$seccion=$_POST["seccion"];
$n_art=$_POST["nombre_articulo"];
$precio=$_POST["precio"];
$fecha=$_POST["fecha"];
$importado=$_POST["importado"];
$p_origen=$_POST["p_origen"];

try { 
    $base=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruebas", "root", "");

    $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $base->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8"); 
    $sql= "INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS ('CÓDIGOARTÍCULO', 'SECCIÓN', 'NOMBREARTÍCULO', 'PRECIO', 'FECHA', 'IMPORTADO', 'PAÍSDEORIGEN') VALUES (:c_articulo, :seccion, :n_art, :precio, :fecha, :importado, :p_origen)";

    $resultado = $base->prepare($sql); 

    $resultado->execute(array(":c_articulo"=>$c_articulo, ":seccion"=>$seccion, ":n_art"=>$n_art, ":precio"=>$precio, ":fecha"=>$fecha,":importado"=>$importado, ":p_origen"=>$p_origen)); 

    echo "Hemos insertado el registro";
    $resultado->closeCursor();
}           
catch(Exception $e){ 
    die ("Error: " . $e->GetMessage() . " En la Linea " .  $e->getline());
}
```

Codigo del formulario para insertar los datos:

```
<form action="pagina_busqueda_pdo.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<table>     
    <tr><td><label>C.Artículo<input type="text" name="c_articulo" placeholder="Código Articulo"></label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Seccion<input type="text" name="seccion" value=""></label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Nombre Art<input type="text" name="nombre_articulo" value=""></label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Precio<input type="text" name="precio" value=""></label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Fecha<input type="text" name="fecha" value=""></label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>¿Importado?<input type="text" name="importado" value=""></label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Pais de Origen<input type="text" name="p_origen" value=""></label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Dev.Joel Listo, Codigo agregado en formato texto

Comment: ¿Si ejecutás esa consulta desde la consola SQL de phpmyadmin, sigue mostrando ese error?

Comment: Si, me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: @VictorEscalona recomiendo modificar los nombres de las columnas _(sin tildes )_ como primera medida ya que puede ocasionar errores ahora o posterior , y segundo elimina las comillas simples ,solo deja los nombres de las columnas.

Comment: Probá poniendo los atributos sin la comilla simple: INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS (CÓDIGOARTÍCULO, SECCIÓN, NOMBREARTÍCULO, PRECIO, FECHA, IMPORTADO, PAÍSDEORIGEN)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La primera recomendación como mencioné en mi comentario , evitar el uso de palabras con tilde y ñ para nombre de columnas o tablas a menudo pueden causar error ahora o posterior.

Luego hay conceptos  que quizá no están claros lo cuál puede que estén ocasionando errores de sintaxis.

- `'`  se usa para adjuntar literales de cadena , es decir pasar una cadena simplemente
- `  se para adjuntar identificadores como nombres de tabla y columna

La solución eliminar las comillas simples para las columnas de la tabla

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS (CODIGOARTICULO, SECCION, NOMBREARTICULO, PRECIO, 
      FECHA, IMPORTADO, PAISDEORIGEN)  VALUES 
      (:c_articulo, :seccion, :n_art, :precio, :fecha, :importado, :p_origen)";
```

o usar la segunda opción para ambos casos ya tomo en cuenta la modificación de las columnas y eliminar las tildes.

```
  $sql= "INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS (`CODIGOARTICULO`, `SECCION`, `NOMBREARTICULO`, `PRECIO`, 
          `FECHA`, `IMPORTADO`, `PAISDEORIGEN`)  VALUES 
          (:c_articulo, :seccion, :n_art, :precio, :fecha, :importado, :p_origen)";
```

Answer (score 0):

mi recomendación es que utilices marcadores de posición en la SQL, y al execute le pases un array con las variables que recibes por POST y no usar las comillas ni tildes en los nombres de los campos, de esta manera:

```
$c_articulo=$_POST["c_articulo"];
$seccion=$_POST["seccion"];
$n_art=$_POST["nombre_articulo"];
$precio=$_POST["precio"];
$fecha=$_POST["fecha"];
$importado=$_POST["importado"];
$p_origen=$_POST["p_origen"];

try { 
  $base=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruebas", "root", "");
  $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $base->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

  $sql= "INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS (CODIGOARTÍCULO, SECCION, NOMBREARTICULO, PRECIO, FECHA, IMPORTADO, PAISDEORIGEN) 
                                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

  $resultado = $base->prepare($sql); 

  $resultado->execute(array($c_articulo,$seccion,$n_art,$precio,$fecha,$importado,$p_origen)); 

 echo "Hemos insertado el registro";
 $resultado->closeCursor();
}           
 catch(Exception $e){ 
 die ("Error: " . $e->GetMessage() . " En la Linea " .  $e->getline());
}
```